# SelectionChanged not work

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I tried many weeks to realize `Selection Changed`, but I can't do this because `SelectedIndex` is always `-1`. Help me please.
Source code:

```
private void MondayListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (MondayListBox.SelectedIndex == -1)
        MessageBox.Show("nain!!"+ MondayListBox.SelectedIndex.ToString()+"");
        //return;

        // Navigate to the new page
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/data.xaml?selectedItem=" + MondayListBox.SelectedIndex, UriKind.Relative));

        // Reset selected index to -1 (no selection)
        MondayListBox.SelectedIndex = -1;
}
```

Comment: have you copied this code from other solution?

Comment: I can't understand what you try to do. The ListBox class doesn't have event called SelectionChanged at all....Use SelecdedIndexChanged event

Comment: @PradeepKesharwani, yes, I was this code, but application-original normal worked

Comment: @Lev, listbox in Visual Studio 2012 for Windows Phone have only SelectionChanged event and haven't SelecdedIndexChanged event

Comment: First of all, why you didn't tell that your question is about windows phone at the beggining??? Please tag your question correctly. Unfortunately, I can't halp you about windows phone...